# transaction got reverted after call deposit function of weth, very strange behavior

Tags: solidity, ether, evm, bsc

```
    address private immutable owner;
    IWETH private constant WETH = IWETH(0x358AA13c52544ECCEF6B0ADD0f801012ADAD5eE3);

    receive() external payable {
        if (msg.value > 0) {
        WETH.deposit{value: msg.value}();
        // owner.call{value: msg.value}(); also reverted
      }
    }

    function withdraw() external onlyOwner {
        uint256 wethBalance = WETH.balanceOf(address(this));

        if (wethBalance > 0) { WETH.withdraw(wethBalance); }
    }
```

if I call withdraw, transaction will be reverted.

transaction got reverted after deposit in receive. I wonder why, calling other functions inside receive function also causes transaction reverted.

tenderly shows very strange error message. https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/bsc/0x98a6b3744f9a413ba1a8e4b45be568591817c6af1c9f44ca7099261d84405dd5